Parsing through a JSON table
I have a problem I would like assistance with dbfiddle.uk/5besOGoU
I can't get the tables to work for the Balance_Sheet.
SELECT
j1.*
-- ,j2.*
,j3.*
FROM OPENJSON(@response)
  WITH (
    request nvarchar(max),
    [type] nvarchar(max),
    results nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) j1
outer APPLY OPENJSON(j1.results)
  WITH (
    results_type nvarchar(100) '$.type',
    results_id nvarchar(100) '$.id',
    segmentation nvarchar(max) '$.tables.segmentation' AS JSON,
    financial_statement_restate_json nvarchar(max) '$.tables.financial_statements_restate' AS JSON
  ) j2
        outer APPLY OPENJSON(j2.segmentation)
          WITH (
                [period_3m_currency_id] nvarchar(max) '$.period_3m.currency_id',
                [period_3m_fiscal_year_end] nvarchar(max) '$.period_3m.fiscal_year_end',
                [period_3m_period] nvarchar(max) '$.period_3m.period',
                [period_3m_report_type] nvarchar(max) '$.period_3m.report_type',
                [period_3m_accounts_payable] nvarchar(max) '$.period_3m.accounts_payable',
                [period_3m_accounts_receivable] nvarchar(max) '$.period_3m.accounts_receivable'
            )
          j3


Why not? What have you tried? I don't see anything in the T-SQL code that's referencing the financial_statement_restate_json that you're extracting.

did you guys see the dbfiddle and the sql above - https://dbfiddle.uk/honFeWfg   I,m trying to get the balance_sheet columns to populate. TY in advance.

Why are you doing outer APPLY OPENJSON(j2.segmentation) rather than outer APPLY OPENJSON(j2.financial_statement_restate_json) What is the relevance of the segmentation property? Are the property names in financial_statements_restate such as period_3m and period_12m completely dynamic and based off the segmentation property?
